# In Careers 2.0 how many repos needed to create a profile

Tags: support, jobs, github

how many repos are needed in git hub to be able to create a profile, I have 5 <del>2</del> repos in github, but is not enough, I get

> We had a look at your GitHub activity but it didn’t quite meet our
>   threshold just yet. We  look at a
>   combination of things, such as commit
>   activity over time.
>
> Our advice? Create some repos or increase the activity on your existing
>   ones. Then feel free to come back to
>   this page and try again.

Comment: I believe 3. That was enough for me to have a "complete" profile.

Comment: Hi, just tried and uploaded another one, but still nothing, now I have 3 and one forked, and nothing yet haha, I will continue uploading and checking, is there a maximum number of repos? tnx

Comment: considering there are other criteria, it is possible that the number of project alone isn't enough.

Comment: It’s a secret! But we will say that we look at # of repos and the time span over which they’ve been active. It ain’t perfect but we want people that actually use the stuff.

Comment: can someone take a look at my profile to see what I am mainly missing from my repos? While the content is mostly elementary, it is definitely serious work.

Comment: @MattSherman: Could you answer this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131652/what-are-the-rough-requirements-for-a-careers-account-via-github-and-shouldnt I'm not asking for the exact requirements, more of a "why are the requirements so lax?"