# What are the rough requirements for a Careers account via GitHub, and shouldn't they be more strict?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, jobs

So I was rooting around Careers, trying to discover what it exactly *was*.

I saw the invite-only thingy, but found out that you could get one via GitHub. Fully expecting to have it declined, I try the GitHub option. And, surprisingly, I get an account{*}.

I'm not that active on GitHub (Technically, I'm not even a programmer)--I created an account just recently, and most of my commits are minor changes. I do participate in a collaborative project, but I've just made a small commit to it (it recently shifted to Git, so my previous commits aren't there).

So, I'd like to ask: What are the *rough* requirements for an account via GitHub? (Rough since it's probably all hush-hush due to gaming)

Also, shouldn't they be made stricter? If a guy like me can get in, *anyone* can ;-)

Just for the record, my GitHub profile is: https://github.com/Manishearth .

<sup>*Now that I have one, I'd like to keep it, thank you very much :)</sup>

Comment: By the upvotes, I see that everybody agrees with me that I don't deserve an account ;-)

Comment: We're just persuaded (or scared to death) by the argument that *"If a guy like me can get in, anyone can"*

Comment: And there was me feeling proud of my unexpected invite.

Comment: I have a GitHub account, but I have never received any.

Comment: @UNNI: I didn't get an invite, I just went to the careers page and tried to sign up and clicked the github option. There was a GitHub option. Additionally, there is some requirement--just an account doesn't suffice. I'm saying that the requirement is _probably_ too low.

Comment: @Manishearth, I think to get listed either you have good reputation here or have a github project.Even if a persons reputation is very low and has a GitHub project, I think he has equal chances.

Comment: @UNNI You either have to get an invite (others can invite you, or I think SE can invite you if you have enough rep.) This is a human mediated process. The GitHub thing seems to be instantaneous(if you have a reasonably active project) , and unrelated to rep. In fact, it is explicitly listed that even if you have low rep, you still have very good chances of getting a job via Careers.

Comment: @Manishearth,you are right.Try to set up a project in Github and see the changes.:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're working on a change that will raise the bar here, but I wanted to clarify that the goal is "demonstrate that you're a programmer".  It's *not* "demonstrate that you are an extra super awesome programmer" -- that's what your profile is for, and ultimately employers will be the judge of that.

If I were reviewing your GitHub by hand, I'd probably give you an invite anyway based on it: it's real code that you wrote and committed.  That's enough to put you in the top 0.001% of people on the internet who might try to create a profile.

With that said, we did realize that we can and should take followers / watchers into account, since that's an implicit peer endorsement of your code.

[update] We adjusted the algorithm to increase the requirements just a bit.

Comment: Why would an employer pay to have access to "programmers"? They already have that. "good programmers" is, IMHO, what you should be aiming for. But the watchers/etc sounds like a great way to do that filtering :)

Comment: @Tim "Good" means different things to different people, and ends up being more of a matching problem with companies.  Trust me, we're spending a lot of time thinking about that as well and making sure that employers see the best matches first.